# How to get hex color main category (not exact name)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Are there breakpoints between HTML main colors to do some calculation against them? I mean if we we have some hex like

```
var a = "#117A65";
var b = "#A04000";
var c = "#922B21";
var d = "#717D7E";
```

Can we calculate them to see in which range of following main colors they are sitting?

```
Red Colors
Pink Colors
Orange Colors
Yellow Colors
Purple Colors
Green Colors 
Blue Colors
Black Colors
```

Comment: Who says they're the main colours? Where are the boundaries between them?

Comment: That's exactly my question I am looking for some boundaries in this example or if you think there is a better way to create boundary between like 10 colors

Comment: That seems entirely opinion-based and not really a programming question.

Comment: Color terms and their boundaries are subjective and different in different cultures. There isn't a clear objective way to do this.

Comment: Thanks for comment Mark but Red is Red everywhere. This is a simple case just let see a Hex is between a rannge or not?

Comment: Your wrong @MonaCoder, do a little research into color terms. There's a vast literature. Here's a good starter bibliography: http://ling-blogs.bu.edu/lx500f10/files/2010/09/lx500univf10-03a-colors-handout.pdf

Comment: Ok let me be more clear and please do not mix other thing with this. Is there any way we can create Range between colors? like say From `000` to `CCC` is grayish? I am not seeing any subjective - objective philosophical point here

Comment: How about this, Mona? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11_color_names#Color_name_chart

Comment: Or this one, they've broke it down to the categories you wanted: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#X11_color_names

Comment: @I.R.R. - You encounter a lot of difficulties building broad categories. For example how do you decide if `Teal` on that chart goes in the green category or the blue? If you are a Japanese speaker you might have a different answer than an English speaker. In fact if you look at the [Japanese version of that page](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/ウェブカラー#X11_color_names) you will see that  the entire`cyan` category is missing. The cyan colors are broken up between between midori (green) and ao (blue). Where those colors spilt isn't the same as where and english speaker might split them.

Comment: @MarkMeyer hey I agree with you this is highly subjective and difficult to proceed. I just thought that link would be a good place to start if she wants to take on this task.

Comment: @I.R.R, one thing you could try is to take a data set like the X11 colors as a source of truth. Then given a color, find the euclidean distance between that color and the colors on the list, pick the closest one, and go with that category. RGB space is not perceptually uniform, so it's not ideal. You could convert everything to LAB which will help with the uniformity, but increase the amount of code you need to write (there are some good JS libraries that can help).

Comment: Maybe it would be helpful to talk about why you think you want to do this. Otherwise it's likely an XY problem.